# Trying to UPDATE the SELECTED row from the database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to give my client a way to SELECT a specific row by typing the id which is the auto incremented primary key of the table.

But there's an issue Showing the Selected row to the client using Text Boxes and letting the client UPDATE the row's cells by editing the Text Boxes and pressing another button.

I'd be glad if you guide be how to do this since I haven't got any help from the search results.

Here's the uncompleted code:

```
private void LookUpBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (UserIDUpdateTB.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Customer ID is needed.", "Error");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-8QAH8VK\SQLDB; Initial Catalog=Restaurant_DB; Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand lookforcustomer = new SqlCommand("LookForCustomer", con);
        lookforcustomer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        lookforcustomer.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", UserIDUpdateTB.Text);
        //lookforcustomer.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataReader reader = lookforcustomer.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        object test = reader.GetValue(1);

        MessageBox.Show(test.ToString(), "Error");

        var id = (int?)lookforcustomer.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Here's the user interface:

[image: Picture]

The client enters the customer ID , presses the look up button and five cells of the row which belongs to the entered ID, appear in five other Text Boxes separately. the client makes whatever changes he/she wants by Changing the Text Boxes' text and pressing the "Update Info" button.

I'd be thankful if you help.

Comment: `But there's an issue`  and that would be....?   Are all the users required to have all the PKs memorized for all the customers?

Comment: You just need an UPDATE command/procedure with parameters for each column and a WHERE clause that takes the userid as a paramter.

Comment: @Plutonix No of course there is a data grid to show the list of customers with their ids . this is something away from that . The problem is that I don't know how to use both SELECT and UPDATE commands to make what I mentioned happen.

Comment: @Crowcoder I know how it works but I'm a bit confused about the code.

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` and should each be in `using` blocks, then you won't need the `Close` because the Dispose will handle that for you. And [Can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a sql/database question, its a question regarding your UI.  I'm assuming its WPF, although WinForms properties were pretty similar too.

Each button should have a separate `_Click` event right?  So in the `UpdateInfo_click`, you can either send a full `UPDATE` statement to SQL, or detect changes between a model in memory and what is in each `TextBox.Text` and only update those which change (or best yet in the where clause say `WHERE Name = {old value}`)

Also on each of your buttons you can set a `Command=` property, which is needed if this were part of a repeater or similar, and you can have the same handler inspect what command it was called with to determine the action needing to be taken

Answer (score 0):

So I think if I understand right, basically what you want to do is pull a customers information when the lookup button is clicked, and update the customers information when the submit button is clicked. Possibly you want to also be able to add new records?

Some of the data readers are a little different, I've used Odbc and Npgsql. But I will try and show the basics of what you want below.

I like to have a separate class that deals with the Database connection, I use a method similar to this to run queries.

```
private SqlDataReader Query(string query)
{
        SqlCommand command = null;
        SqlDataReader result_reader = null;

        try
        {
            //conn.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(query_to_perform, database_connection); //database_connection is the same as the as your "con" variable
            result_reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            this.successful_query = true;
            this.error_message = "";
            //conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            this.successful_query = false;
            this.error_message = ex.Message;
            //destroy the connection on a failure
            database_connection = new SqlConnection();
            throw;
        }
        return result_reader;
}
```

Next we basically need to fill the text boxes from a select statement where the customer id is equal to the customer id on the table

```
private void LookUpBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = ConnectionClass.Query("SELECT * WHERE customer_id = '" + customerIdTextbox.Text + "';")
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        //reader[0] probably is CustomerId
        NameTextbox.Text = reader[1].ToString();
        LastNameTextbox.Text = reader[2].ToString();
        PhoneNumberTextbox.Text = reader[3].ToString();
        CellphoneNumberTextbox.Text = reader[4].ToString();
        AddressTextbox.Text = reader[5].ToString();
    }
}
```

Update the customer, I'd suggest disabling the CustomerId box after they pull up an account, or they might change the number and update a different customer with all the information pulled from the first customer,

```
private void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (//!exists)
    {
        CreateNewCustomer();
    }
    else
    {
       ConnectionClass.Query("UPDATE table SET name = '" + NameTextbox.Text + "', lastname = '" + LastNameTextbox.Text + "', phonenumber = '" + PhoneNumberTextbox.Text + "', cellphonenumber = '" + CellphoneNumberTextbox.Text + "', address = '" + AddressTextbox.Text + "' WHERE CustomerID = '" + customerIdTextbox.Text + '";");
    }
}
```

I believe this should give you the very basics of what you are trying to do, you can still do the queries the way you were if you don't want to create a separate class to deal with the db connection. You might also want to look in to preventing SQL Injections, you will need to deal with things like apostrophes in the text, and creating a new customer will just use an insert query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guide. I was wondering is it fine if I use stored procedure command type instead of query string?

Comment: @SinaR You can, I would just make a separate method for it, and instead of a string that has a raw query in it, have it take a string with the stored procedures name. You can still return a SQLDataReader. Should be the same everywhere else.